# How To Save Entire Mouse-Over Zoom Image From Website

Tags: zoom

I was wondering if there was a way to save an entire mouse-over zoom image from a website? For example....some retailers use mouse-over zoom but you can only see a small portion of the entire zoomed image in a pop-up window. Is there a way to save the entire zoomed large-scale image?

Comment: You could use the 'print screen' button and paste it to a notepad or paint document.

Comment: It really depends on the site. You should be able to View Source and find the location of the full-size image file with a little digging (do a Find on .jpg or .png)